# How to deal with the arguments when inheriting float class in python?

Tags: python

I want to make a new class that is both a float type and has some custom attributes as follows

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print('Father', a, b)


class Son(Father, float):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Son, self).__init__(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    son = Son(1, "b")
    print(son.a)
```

but it reports

```
TypeError: float expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

I have tried to modified the class `Son` as follows but it doesn't work.

```
class Son(Father, float):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        Father.__init__(a, b)
        float.__init__(self)
```

Also, the following code reports the same error, but I don't know why.

```
class Son(float):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Son, self).__init__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    son = Son(1, "b")
    print(son)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, because you inherit from `float` you must handle `__new__`:

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print('Father', a, b)


class Son(Father, float):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        # float.__new__ requires a single arugment
        return super().__new__(cls, a)
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    son = Son(1, "b")
    print(son.a)
```

But you should really consider if instead of inheritance you should be using composition or another approach. Why inherit from float?

Comment: I think he also can use descriptors instead of inheritance

Comment: And to be noted sum (and most other dunder methods) of 2 sons will produce float `print(type(son + son))  # <class 'float'>`

Comment: @sudden_appearance yes, the built-in types are mostly closed to extension

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, there are some mixins provided, e.g. `MutableMapping`, but mostly - you're right